# Saving text to a txt file on a html server?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a small website and I've run into a problem. I want to save a number that is hardcoded to a .txt file on the press of a button.

I've already tried some examples online from other website but the only time I could same something was when I used PHP and it wasn't on a button press.

```
...
<br>
<br><table id="tblCustomers" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%;">
        <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' 
         %}'">Execute Script</button> <hr>
             //On this button it should save a 23 to a txt 
               file which is in the same folder and has the 
               name contacts.txt                 
        </td>
        <td style="width: 50%;"><input type="button" 
         id="btnread" value="Count Rows" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
```

this is something else I tried it doesn't work either.

Comment: use ajax to send a request to a php script or submit a form to a php script. The PHP script will write the data to file rather than javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly write to a file with Javascript - the security implications of being able to do so do not bear thinking about. What you can do though is ( or one of them anyway ) would be to use Javascript to send the request to save the data to a backend script that does have access and ability to write to files on the server.

For example - using the `fetch` api to send a request to the PHP script ( it is the same document here for demo but could be an entirely different script ) - the PHP code processes the fetch request and performs one of two tasks - either write data to the file or read from it before sending the response for the fetch callback to process / play with.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $file='test-contacts.txt';  #   write to this file
        $json=json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );    #   get the request body

        $action=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'action') ? $json->action : false;
        $value=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'value') ? $json->value : false;


        switch( $action ){
            case 'execute':
                $data = array( 'bytes'=>file_put_contents( $file, $value . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND ), 'value'=>$value, 'time'=>time() );
            break;
            case 'count':
                $data=array( 'bytes'=>filesize( $file ), 'time'=>time(), 'count'=>sizeof( file( $file ) ) );
            break;
            default:
                http_response_code( 400 );
                exit( json_encode('error') );
        }

        http_response_code( 200 );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                /* find and assign event handler to the buttons */
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('td > input[ type="button" ]') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        /* prepare the Fetch request */
                        let url=location.href;
                        let options={ 
                            method:'post',
                            headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
                            body:JSON.stringify({ 
                                action:this.name,
                                value:23 /* seems very peculiar hard-coding a value to be written to file!!! */
                            })
                        };
                        /* The callback to process returned JSON data */
                        const callback=function( json ){
                            let out=document.querySelector( 'output' );
                                out.innerHTML='';
                            Object.keys( json ).map( k=>{
                                let div=document.createElement('div')
                                    div.innerText=[k,json[k]].join('=');
                                out.appendChild( div );
                            });                     
                        };
                        /* If there are errors... */
                        const errorcallback=function(err){
                            alert( err )
                        };
                        /* Send the request and manipulate the response */
                        fetch( url, options )   
                            .then( r=>{ return r.json() })
                            .then( callback )
                            .catch( errorcallback );
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='tblCustomers'>
            <tr>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

If attempting to record different values ( as a comment suggested ) a minor change to the structure of the data would be advisable so that each ID can be logged properly. The comment I made regarding a database still stands however but perhaps the following might be of use.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $file='test-contacts.txt';  #   write to this file
        $json=json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );    #   get the request body

        $action=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'action') ? $json->action : false;
        $value=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'value') ? intval( $json->value ) : false;


        $data=file_exists( $file ) ? json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ) ) : new stdclass;

        switch( $action ){

            case 'execute':
                $data->$value=isset( $value ) && isset( $data->$value ) ? $data->$value + 1 : 1;
                file_put_contents( $file, json_encode( $data ) );
            break;

            case 'count':
                $value=isset( $data->$value ) ? $data->$value : 0;
                $data=new stdclass;
                $data->count=$value;
            break;

            default:
                http_response_code( 400 );
                exit( json_encode('error') );
        }

        http_response_code( 200 );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                /* find and assign event handler to the buttons */
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('td > input[ type="button" ]') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        /* prepare the Fetch request */
                        let url=location.href;
                        let options={ 
                            method:'post',
                            headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
                            body:JSON.stringify({ 
                                action:this.name,
                                value:this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id
                            })
                        };
                        /* The callback to process returned JSON data */
                        const callback=function( json ){
                            let out=document.querySelector( 'output' );
                                if( out ) out.innerHTML='';

                            Object.keys( json ).map( k=>{
                                let div=document.createElement('div')
                                    div.innerText=[ k, json[ k ] ].join('=');
                                out.appendChild( div );
                            });                     
                        };
                        /* If there are errors... */
                        const errorcallback=function(err){
                            alert( err )
                        };
                        /* Send the request and manipulate the response */
                        fetch( url, options )   
                            .then( response => { return response.json() } )
                            .then( callback )
                            .catch( errorcallback );
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='tblCustomers'>
            <tr data-id=23>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=24>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=25>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=26>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Delete entry or delete entire contents can be done like so:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $file='test-contacts.txt';  #   write to this file
        $json=json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );    #   get the request body

        $action=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'action') ? $json->action : false;
        $value=!empty( $json ) && property_exists( $json, 'value') ? intval( $json->value ) : false;


        $data=file_exists( $file ) ? json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ) ) : new stdclass;

        switch( $action ){

            case 'execute':
                $data->$value=isset( $value ) && isset( $data->$value ) ? $data->$value + 1 : 1;
                file_put_contents( $file, json_encode( $data ) );
            break;

            case 'count':
                $value=isset( $data->$value ) ? $data->$value : 0;
                $data=new stdclass;
                $data->count=$value;
            break;

            case 'clear':
                $data=unlink( $file );
            break;

            case 'delete':
                if( property_exists( $data, $value ) && !empty( $data->$value ) ){
                    unset( $data->$value );
                    file_put_contents( $file, json_encode( $data ) );
                }
            break;

            default:
                http_response_code( 400 );
                exit( json_encode('error') );
        }

        http_response_code( 200 );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                /* find and assign event handler to the buttons */
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('td > input[ type="button" ]') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        /* prepare the Fetch request */
                        let url=location.href;
                        let options={ 
                            method:'post',
                            headers:{ 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
                            body:JSON.stringify({ 
                                action:this.name,
                                value:this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id
                            })
                        };
                        /* The callback to process returned JSON data */
                        const callback=function( json ){
                            let out=document.querySelector( 'output' );
                                if( out ) out.innerHTML='';

                            Object.keys( json ).map( k=>{
                                let div=document.createElement('div')
                                    div.innerText=[ k, json[ k ] ].join('=');
                                out.appendChild( div );
                            });                     
                        };
                        /* If there are errors... */
                        const errorcallback=function(err){
                            alert( err )
                        };
                        /* Send the request and manipulate the response */
                        fetch( url, options )   
                            .then( response => { return response.json() } )
                            .then( callback )
                            .catch( errorcallback );
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='tblCustomers'>
            <tr data-id=23>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete record' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='clear' value='Clear file' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=24>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete record' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='clear' value='Clear file' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=25>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete record' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='clear' value='Clear file' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-id=26>
                <td><input type='button' name='execute' value='Execute Script' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='count' value='Count Rows' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete record' /></td>
                <td><input type='button' name='clear' value='Clear file' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but if i try to implement this code it gives me this error mssg as an alert SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Use the console to inspect the error - for me the above code worked with no errors so it is hard to diagnose why it does not work for you

Comment: I have fixed the syntax it was just a typo, but now i have another error TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Also i use these specific values because i will change the buttons later and each button should give me another value in the text file so that i can later see in the text file what the users have clicked

Comment: and thank you for being this pacient this is my first time writing html, before i only written in python and java. I basicly just learned the parts that i know in html yesterday

Comment: The TypeError ~ do you have an `output` element? With regards to other comment about saving specific values etc to see what users have clicked... That suggests, to me, using a slightly different approach to how the data that is recorded. If this is to be a production site then a text-file is really not a good choice - a database would be the better solution by far!

Comment: if you did that you would need to change `value:this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id` to `value:this.parentNode.dataset.id` ~ where `this` refers to the button that was clicked in this case and it's parent is the `td` etc

Comment: pleasure - good luck with the rest of your project... think about using a database though ;-)

Comment: Yeah i stumbled across that to but this is a weekend project and me being familia with java and python was obviosly the first thing i thought was just to use a txt file :).

Comment: I still have a question since ur very familiar with this is there a simular way to make a button to remove one or all entrys of the file?

Comment: In short, Yes! You can easily do both but the code required for both is a little different. To delete the file or erase the entire content can be done in a single line - to delete a single entry is more convoluted